# How to convert on the client side GPX and KML to JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, kml, gpx

How to convert GPX and KML to JSON, is known any client-side solution? Can be detected file format by selecting by one button? I work with MongoDB and I found solution in ruby but i don't want this process on the server. Whether this can be done in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably multiple solutions. You could just load the XML and then parse it by walking the DOM, but if you use jQuery, you could use this for instance:
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/